# Fixing mod_rewrite and mod_alias conflict

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, codeigniter, clean-urls, mod-alias

I have a VirtualHost setup like this :

```
Alias /somedir /some/other/dir
```

http://example.com/somedir works fine

However, I need to setup `mod_rewrite` for /somedir (a CodeIgniter app for which I want clean URLs). Here's the bit from the CodeIgniter wiki :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Usually, when `mod_rewrite` is used in subdirs changing `RewriteBase` to match the name of the dir is enough to make it work :

```
RewriteBase /somedir
```

...but it doesn't seem to work with `mod_alias` (getting 404s). Is there a workaround for this problem ?

Comment: On a side note: when including mock-urls, use example.com as the domain name, that's what it is for. I doubt you are the owner of site.com :)

Comment: Where have you defined your `mod_rewrite` rules?

Comment: @Wrikken ups...my bad, thanks for correcting that :).
@Tim, in a `.htaccess` file at the root of the aliased dir. I've also tried setting them in the vhost config file, with the same effects.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked on my test server, so trying this might solve your problem..

In your virtual host:

```
Alias /somedir /some/other/dir

RewriteEngine On

# I think these conditions should work correctly; the other ones shouldn't
# because the alias has not been applied at this stage of processing yet
RewriteCond /some/other/dir%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond /some/other/dir%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
# L is unnecessary in this context, but be sure to PT so mod_alias picks up
# on the rewrite
RewriteRule ^/somedir/(.*)$ /somedir/index.php/$1 [PT]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not working... I've tried putting it in `.htaccess`, at the root of the aliased dir, in a `<Location>` block in the vhost config, still no go.

Comment: Did you try putting it in the vhost config outside of any `<Location>`/`<Directory>` blocks? I'll test with the `.htaccess` later though and see if I can figure out why that might not be working either.

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't tested your sample, in my own configurations, I haven't had much success with the PT flag, perhaps because of interactions with re-write rules in my config.

I've found it easier to restrict my use of aliases to the rewrite conditions, and always use the a file system path in the rewrite output.

```
Define SOME_DIR = "/somedir"
Define SOME_OTHER_PATH = "/some/other/dir"

Alias "${SOME_DIR}" "${SOME_OTHER_PATH}"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond ${SOME_DIR}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond ${SOME_DIR}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f

RewriteRule ^${SOME_DIR}/(.*)$ ${SOME_OTHER_PATH}/index.php/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```